No Internet connection overlay unuable to render image
Need help on one of the use cases where we need to render the images when there is no internet.
We need to show the No-Internet-Connection overlay when there is no internet.But when component is loaded when there is no internet its not rendering the images since component is loaded for the first time.How can i load images to this component in advance and used it for rendering in UI?
I was thinking if there is a way to store the static image in the browser session when the application is being loaded for the first time.
